# How to delete a row from a Datatable

Tags: datatables

I am trying to delete a row from a table if 3 values match but am having some issues.

What I have is the following:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#st').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": false,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
      if ( data[1] == data[2] && data[2] == data[3] ) {
              $(row).addClass('table-success');
              $(row).remove();
          }
      }
    });
});
```

It colors the row correctly (I added that to test the logic), but it is not deleting the row.
I have tried a few different answers from the docs, but they all fail. The above fails silently, which does not help.

According to the docs, I also tried the following:

```js
var table = $('#st').DataTable({
```

and then tried to delete as follow:

```js
table.row($(row)).remove();
```

This fails with `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined`

The table rows are created as follow:

```php
              <?php
                foreach ($vfile as $key => $value) {
                  if (empty($value['latest_version'])) { continue; }
              ?>
                <tr>
                  <td> <?php echo $value['module']; ?> </td>
                  <td> <?php echo $value['latest_version']; ?> </td>
                  <?php foreach ($st_envs as $k => $v) { 
                    $vrs = !empty($value[$v]) ? $value[$v] : 'Not Included';
                    echo "<td>" . $vrs  . "</td>";
                  }
                  ?>
                </tr>
              <?php } ?>
```

I am pretty new to JS and the works, so am a little lost as to where to start - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get "*Cannot read property 'row' of undefined*" because `table` not is initialised. The Api is simply not yet passed back to the variable reference at the time `createdRow` is executed.

But inside DT's callbacks you always have `this`, which actually is the dataTable (jQuery) instance of the DataTable API. So

```js
createdRow: function ( row, data, index ) {
  if ( data[1] == data[2] && data[2] == data[3] ) {
    $(row).addClass('table-success')
    this.api().row(row).remove() //<-----
  }
}
```